# elided_page_range paginator not functioning as expected

Tags: django

I implemented a paginator based on [this blog post](https://nemecek.be/blog/105/how-to-use-elided-pagination-in-django-and-solve-too-many-pages-problem) with a goal of having a paginator that looks something like this so I don't have a ton of pages being display

[image]

view

```
def home(request):

page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
paginator = Paginator(Post.objects.all(), 1)
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
page_range = paginator.get_elided_page_range(number=page)

context = {'page_range': page_range, 'page': page, 'paginator': paginator, 'page_obj': page_obj}

return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

template

```
    <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for post in page_obj %}

        <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.year }}</a>
        <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center flex-wrap mt-2 mb-4">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled page-item"><span class="page-link">&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in page_range|default_if_none:page_obj.paginator.get_elided_page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                <li class="active page-item"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                {% if i == page_obj.paginator.ELLIPSIS %}
                    <li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">{{ i }}</span></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled page-item"><span class="page-link">&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>

</main>
```

The paginator works except it is displaying every page and not showing the ellipses
[image]

Theres not alot of info online about using the elided_page_range and from what I see in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_elided_page_range) it should be working correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to print what `paginator.get_elided_page_range(number=page)` gives you in your view

Comment: in the template if I printed it ``<a>{{ paginator.get_elided_page_range(number=page)}}</a>`` I get the error ``Could not parse the remainder: '(number=page)' from 'paginator.get_elided_page_range(number=page)'`` going to do some more debugging and see what happens. However I do believe this is an error associated with the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just doing this instead

template:

```
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example " class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">               
                <li class="page-item">
                    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                    {% else %}
                </li>

                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endif %} {% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %} {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ i }}</a>
                </li>
                {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and i < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% endif %} {% endfor %}

                <li class="page-item">
                    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                    {% else %}
                </li>

                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}                
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[image]

[image]